# create-react-app exclude folder from triggering reload

Tags: javascript, electron, create-react-app, writefile

I have a use case where I'm dynamically storing a pdf file in my public folder.
`public/print-preview/`.

The issue here is that the application reloads and the state gets lost after such a file was created and stored.

How can I exclude such a folder from being watched? And is there a way to achieve this without ejecting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/2541 :

> I don't think we'll do this as it seems like people generally don't
>   use public folder for uploads. And it wouldn't work in production
>   anyway.
>
> I would recommend to use a separate server (which you need anyway) and
>   separate folder for image uploads, and have the app load images from a
>   different host/port (just like it would in production, e.g. from a
>   CDN).

Answer (score 1):

You can open the file `node_modules\react-scripts\config\webpackDevServer.config.js` and change the `watchOptions.ignored` setting to include the public folder like this:

```
watchOptions: {
  ignored: [ ignoredFiles(paths.appSrc), paths.appPublic ]
},
```

Of course this is only temporary as reinstall/updates to node_modules will remove this.

Comment: This causes an error for me because `devServer.watchOptions` is not a valid API option. You can see valid options [here](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserverwatchfiles).

Comment: It looks like you should use `devServer.watchFiles` instead, which uses [Chokidar](https://github.com/paulmillr/chokidar) so you can use any valid options from that. However, I have tried settings a couple of files to be ignored by chokidar and it doesn't seem to have any effect. I even tried ignoring everything: `devServer.watchFiles.options.ignore = ['**/*.*']` but nothing changed